# Hibernate: Element type "hibernate-configuration" must be declared. without migration

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration

I am using maven to integrate my project. I receive common "Element type "hibernate-configuration" must be declared." problem although I did not made any changes to hibernate part of my project. It stopped working by itself.

Exception

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 5 in XML document from class path resource [hibernate.cdf.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 26; Element type "hibernate-configuration" must be declared.
Jun 27, 2019 7:03:22 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 5 in XML document from class path resource [hibernate.cdf.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 26; Element type "hibernate-configuration" must be declared.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources$0(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:358)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:696)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:662)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:587)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:526)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My hibernate.cdf.xml file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property     name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Programmatic configuration:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
@ImportResource(value = {"classpath:hibernate.cdf.xml"})
public class HibernateConfiguration {

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
//System.out.println("HibernateConfiguration : SESSION FACTORY LOADED");
LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String [] {"Entities"});
sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
//System.out.println("HibernateConfiguration : DataSource LOADED");
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/sakila");
dataSource.setUsername("username");
dataSource.setPassword("password");
dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager            (SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

//System.out.println("Obtained sessionFactory: "+sessionFactory);
HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new         HibernateTransactionManager();
transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
return transactionManager;
}

private final Properties hibernateProperties() {

Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();

hibernateProperties.setProperty      ("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

return hibernateProperties;

}

}
```

Maven pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MVC1</groupId>
<artifactId>mvc1</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>mvc1 Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>5.2.12.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
<version>9.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.47</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
<version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>mvc1</finalName>
</build>


</project>
```

I did not version the code and worked on it for some time (5+ months) not out of nowhere the error happened. Could you please suggest changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mapping, I replace by:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

In config, I replace by:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd is the good url but is very unstable since yesterday  :'(

The "redirect 301" to https://hibernate.org seems causing this issue. And using directly https in xml don't work too.

Be careful, old tomcat (6 or before) does not recognize the protocol "classpath://".

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution. Since I am using mainly programmatic configuration I removed @ImportResource(value = {"classpath:hibernate.cdf.xml"}) annotation so that the hibernate.cdf.xml will not be utilized. Then I tried to set properties previously seen in xml using programmatic configuration.

This:

```
<property     name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
```

Can be represented as:

```
hibernateProperties.setProperty  ("org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext", "thread");
hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");
```

Please approve it if you think it's proper.

Answer (score 0):

The DTD file is behind two HTTP redirects (301), and Java's InputStream that reads the XML and validates with the DTD doesn't work well with that. Replace the DTD with:

`https://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd`

So that it's a direct link to it